# IIS seems like to sleep until the next request

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, httpmodule

I have created a httpModule for my Web Application which basically is triggered by a timer on specific schedules, it runs fine and the method I want is invoked after I publish it in IIS but what happens if there is no request it seems like the Web Application stops to a stand still making any scheduled events not to run, It will only run again only if I make a new request.  What am I doing wrong? Can I make my website not sleep so that during times where there is no request the schduled httpModule would run as required?
I hope I made this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check you Application Pool setting there to make sure it does not recycle the working process

**EDIT**
Not sure what version is your IIS, but take IIS7.5 as an example, in the advanced setting of an application pool, there is a setting named like 'Idle Time-out(minutes)' which means after your application idle for that time it will be shut down, also a setting named as Regular Time Interval(minutes) in Recycling section, says it means Period of time the pool will be recycled.

Comment: it is set to 1740 minutes which is 29 hours, do you think when it recycles it just waits for the next request for the application to become active again?

Comment: so how about the setting 'Idle Time-out(minutes)' ? Recycle may just may your application rerun, but timeout make it kills that process I think

Comment: Its set to 20 minutes, will increase that and will let you know if it works.  Thanks for your help so far