# Hangfire Server Sleeps when Inactive

Tags: asp.net, iis, hangfire, application-pool, hangfire-sql

I have set the application pool to:

StartMode - Always Running |
Idle-Timeout (minutes) 0 |
Preload Enanbled = true

I don't understand why my Hangfire Application still sleeps. Also the server was started a second ago after I open the hangfire application. Any suggestion how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.
If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.
We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.
Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yup, the issue is on my Dev Ops. It turns my application pool in to default settings when I check in some changes.

Comment: i request you to post the suggestion and mark it.it will help other people who face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Enable automatic start-up for Windows Process Activation (WAS) and World Wide Web Publishing (W3SVC) services (enabled by default).

Run this below command to set serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" to your site:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='appname']/applicationDefaults" -name "serviceAutoStartEnabled" -value "True"
```

Make sure application pool recycling is disabled:

[image]

Under Recycling, set the Regular Time Interval (minutes) to 0.

[image]

Select Specific Times and either click the > expander arrow to see if there is time specified below or click the ... to see if there are any values in the TimeSpan Collection Editor dialog. If so, clear it out.

[image]

Refer this post for more detail:

[IIS 10 Application Pool fall a sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348433/iis-10-application-pool-fall-a-sleep)